# Using external attribute as document_id returns the name of the attribute AS the document_id

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Whenever i try to assign the document_id with some attribute from the documents, it creates just one new document on ElasticSearch with the document_id as the name of the attribute i'm trying to use. What i want is the actual amount of documents retrieved, with the document_id set as the primary key from the source database.

```
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["placeholder"]
index => "item"
document_id => "%{i.RecordId}"
doc_as_upsert => true
user => "placeholder"
password => "placeholder"
}
}
```

specifically, creates a new document that looks like this;

```
"_index" : "item",
"_type" : "_doc",
"_id" : "%{i.RecordId}",
"_score" : 1.0,
"_source" : {
```

I've tried a few different approaches, like copying the recordid into a metadata field, but nothing has worked so far.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Which version of logstash are you using? Share a sample of your document fields. Does the field `i.RecordId` exists? Is it a field named `i.RecordId` or a json object named `i` with a nested field named `RecordId`, like `{ "i": { "RecordId": "value" } } ` ? Depending on your logstash version the way to access the field is different.

Comment: It's a field from a table in MSSQL. Had to do some joins to get the fields needed - and when i don't try to assign the document_id through the conf file, everything gets mapped correctly. I use version 7.6.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use metadata field, like described on the docs here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-fields.html

You have to assign in your output something like this:

```
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["placeholder"]
index => "item"
document_id => "%{[@metadata][id]}"
doc_as_upsert => true
user => "placeholder"
password => "placeholder"
}
}
```

and you should assign the value of id in your filter, like:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "[@metadata][id]" => <your_id_var> }
}
```

Alternatively you can put this in your filter:

```
  fingerprint {                                                                              
     method => "SHA512"                                                                                    `        source => <YOUR SOURCE>                                                                
    target => "[@metadata][fingerprint]"                                          
  }
```

and then put document_id in the output

```
document_id => "%{[@metadata][fingerprint]}"
```

Comment: i get the same problem, it still only adds one with a document_id that looks like this;

{
        "_index" : "item",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "%[@metadata][_id]%",
        "_score" : 1.0,

Comment: Changing it back didn't help either, still just creates one document with the id "%[@metadata][id]%"

Comment: it seems there is a "%" at the end. 
it should be just "[@metadata][id]" in the filter
and %{[@metadata][id]} in the output

Comment: That helped, however, no matter how i format the field use, it ends up just setting the id e.g as "_id" : "recordid", is there a special way to format this?

Comment: Is "recordid" a field you get from grok filter?

Comment: recordid is a field i get directly from the database;  statement => "SELECT
      i.RecordId,

Comment: can you share your entire logstash config? in this moment you are assigning recordid as a constant and not as a variable. Logstash is not understanding recordid it is a variable that change for each document

Comment: I have included it in a comment further below

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://placeholedr"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Users\Bruger\Documents\JBDC\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar"
    jdbc_user => "sa"
    jdbc_password => "placeholder"
    statement => "SELECT
                  i.RecordId,
                  i.FK_Catalog,
                  i.FK_Unit,
                  c.Name,
                  i.ItemNumber,
                  i.Ean,
                  i.ItemNumber2,
                  i.Description,
                  i.AltDescription,
                  i.IsStandard,
                  i.MarkedForDelete,
                  i.DateCreated,
                  i.DateUpdated,
                  i.ItemNumberNumerical,
                  i.ItemAlias,
                  i.FK_CatalogItemGroup,
                  f.UnitName,
                  i.NetPrice,
                  i.GrossPrice,
                  i.SellingPrice,
                  i.IsSellingPriceCalculated,
                  i.PriceMatrixItemId,
                  i.DiscountPercent,
                  i.DiscountAmount,
                  i.IsActive,
                  i.ItemOnStock,
                  i.AllowanceCharge,
                  w.Name as WholesalerName,
                  w.WholesalerID,
                  wp.Priority
                  from Item as i
                  JOIN Catalog as c on c.RecordId = i.FK_Catalog
                  join Wholesalers w on w.WholesalerID = c.FK_Wholesaler
                  join WholesalerPriority wp on wp.fk_wholesaler = w.WholesalerID
                  JOIN Units f on f.UnitsID = i.FK_Unit 
                  "
  }

}

filter
{
    mutate
        {
            add_field => {"[@metadata][id]" => "[recdordid]"     }      
        }
}



output { 
elasticsearch {
    hosts => [placeholder]
    index => "oegaard"
    doc_as_upsert => true
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][id]}"
    user => "placeholedr"
    password => "placeholder"
  }
}
```